# Why is infinite dimensional space with weak topology not locally bounded (Rudin 3.11)?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

In 3.11 of Rudin's Functional Analysis 2e:

> If $X$ is infinite-dimensional then every weak neighborhood of $0$
> contains an infinite-dimensional subspace; hence  $X_w$  is not locally
> bounded.

Then it is sufficient to show that infinite-dimensional subspace is always unbounded, but there is no search result or in Wikipedia about this. Then what is the reasoning in the above content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is an infinite dimensional topological space such that $X_w$ is locally bounded. Then, there are bounded linear functionals $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, and $\varepsilon>0$ such that  $V=\{x\in X: |\lambda_j(x)|<\varepsilon,\,1\leq j\leq n\}$ is weakly bounded. $V$ contains contains the infinite dimensional subspace $Y=\bigcap^n_{j=1}\{x\in X:\lambda_j(x)=0\}$ and so, $Y$ is weakly bounded. Let $\lambda$ be a bounded linear functional that is not in the span of $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ (this is possible since $X$ is infinite dimensional). Since $Y$ is weakly bounded, there is $t_0>0$ such that $Y\subset t_0\{x\in X:|\lambda (x)|<1\}$. Thus $|\lambda(y)|<t_0$ for all $y\in Y$, and since $Y$ is a linear space, it follows that $\lambda(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$. This implies that $\lambda\in\operatorname{span}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, $X_w$ is not weakly bounded.

Comment: Then infinite-dimensional subspace is not always unbounded (or there will be a trivial proof as in OP)?

Comment: An infinite dimensional space is not weakly locally bounded, that is what I proved. In particular, it can't be weakly bounded...

Comment: @OliverDiaz May I ask why there must be a bounded linear functional $\lambda$, just because X is infinite dimensional.

Comment: @Daaaaa: perhaps the OP should've mentioned that the dual $X^*$ is assumed to separate points of $X$ (that is the case in the book of Rudin). This make $X_w$ a locally convex topological vector space with $(X_w)^*=X^*$. If $X$ is infinite dimensional, then application of the Hanh-Banach-Banch separation theorem implies that $X^*$ is infinite dimensional: for each $x\neq0$, there is $\Lambda_x\in X^*$ such that $\Lambda_xx=1$.